# Email Column Constraint to Contain '@' character

Tags: constraint, oracle-12c

How do you create an inline constraint for a Email Address Field that requires there be an "@" character? Pretty much I want there to be a restriction to the field so that the data entered must have the "@" within it. I'm using Oracle SQL Developer 12c.

Comment: Are you sure that's all you want to worry about? So if the entire string is `@` or `@@` it's valid? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4389432/adding-an-email-check-constraint-in-apex

Comment: Well having the '@' in the email is a start and I'm having trouble figuring out that simple constraint. The REGEXP_LIKE condition looks like it will work but I'm not sure how to use it.

Comment: It will get much more complicated than that, I can assure you. There are all kinds of rules about allowed characters, length of local part, length of domain, collation, and then of course you have to check if the TLD is valid, the domain is valid, and if that is a valid username at that domain. Even then there is no guarantee that an e-mail can be delivered there. Just want to be sure you're aware that there is a lot of work to be done after you've ensured there is an `@` sign in there...

Comment: I definitely did not know how extensive it could be. I'm still in the beginning stages of learning DB Administration.

I'm not really trying to get an email address field in its exact format but just to understand how to create some simple constraints. I would assume I could use this same method for other fields such and requiring that there be a prefix of "cust-" for the customer field or something in that nature.

Comment: That sounds like a smell. If the column is meant to hold customers, putting a `cust-` prefix in every single value in every single row just seems wasteful to me. I get that you're just trying to create a simple constraint but before you start *enforcing* the things, you should really have a good understanding of what *the things* are.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
CREATE TABLE myTable ( email VARCHAR2(254) );
ALTER TABLE myTable ADD CONSTRAINT chk_email_format CHECK ( REGEXP_LIKE(EMAIL, '.{1,64}@.{1,255}'));
```

> INSERT INTO myTable (email) VALUES ('abc abc.com')
>
> Error report -
> SQL Error: ORA-02290: check constraint (FLASHCARD.CHK_EMAIL_FORMAT) violated

254 total characters is from [Errata ID: 1690](http://www.rfc-editor.org/errata_search.php?rfc=3696) with 64 before the @ and up to 255 after it.

This simple regexp, email address must have a @, will alert you to attempts to insert wildly wrong data (perhaps helping catch a bug or two).  However, building a complete RFC 5322 validator is a difficult task.  For details take a look here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/using-a-regular-expression-to-validate-an-email-address